# Node WebKit and SerialPort

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, webkit, node-webkit

I'm developping an application with Node WebKit and I need to access to the SerialPort of my PC (with Windows 8).

For install 3rd party modules with C/C++ addons I followed the guide at the following link:https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Using-Node-modules#3rd-party-modules-with-cc-addons. When I rebuild the module "serialport" (previously installed with "npm install serialport" command) with command "nw-gyp rebuild --target=0.12.4", I obtain the following error:

```
gyp: Undefined variable module_name in binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\LucaG.SEAV\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\nw-gyp\lib\configure.js:353:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Users\\LucaG.SEAV\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modu
les\\nw-gyp\\bin\\nw-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=0.12.2"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Sources\INT2292App\node_modules\serialport
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.40
gyp ERR! nw-gyp -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! not ok
```

and I see that the first error is "gyp: Undefined variable module_name in binding.gyp"

How can I solve this problem?

I'm using the v0.12.3 of Node WebKit

Answer (score 2):

I worked hard to understand how to resolve this. I've built it on Windows 7 sp1 but procedure must not be so different on windows 8.

- **serialport** [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) precise you must install python 2.x and not 3.x.
  so you can find it on main python website http://python.org
- install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 if you don't want to install visual studio. You need to sign in to do so.  You can also use visual studio community edition and install VC++.
- Ensure your environment variable %INCLUDE% point to the right folder.  It must contain **stdio.h**.  Mine is c:\Program files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt.  You can look it in **cmd.exe** by :
  `echo %INCLUDE%`  
  if it's not, you can set it by :
  `set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;YOUR_PATH`
- install required build package globally :

  `npm install -g node-gyp node-pre-gyp nw-gyp`
- Go to your serialport folder and launch build:

  `cd project\node_modules\serialport 
  node-pre-gyp rebuild --runtime=node-webkit --target=0.18.3 --target_arch=x64 --target-platform=win32`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this module have some problems in nwjs. Try my build: https://mega.nz/#!8Rl1BADa!icijUMsn5ndD-TM22K3gwCGGdoN2PUomA3mUjq6pmDY
I used it in real project with nwjs early, but I don't tested it with 12.3 and I don't know if it will works.

Comment: Thank you very much VoidVolker.
I tried to use another build found in internet and seem that it work well (with an old version of node webkit) but, I want to try also your build. Can you give me the passowrd for download it.

Comment: Thank you. As soon as possible I'll try it.